# Delete file in java

Tags: java, file, process, delete-file

I want to delete file on windows OS using java, how ever some time file may be in use by external process, how can I delete forcefully or by knowing which process use that and kill that process or any how, any code or way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call low level Windows routines via JNI (http://www.atwistedweb.com/java/jni.html) or JNA (http://jna.java.net/)

But how about a more simple solution: Download Unlocker and run it with `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 4):

Java doesn't have any built-in tools to find out what process opened specific file. This is OS-specific. You must run some external tools for that, but I don't know any Windows command-line tool allowing you to do that.

Comment: +1 note: There is no such tool; Windows can't delete files which are locked.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: FYI: ther is tool `unlocker` that can do this, so i want to do this in java

Comment: @Nirmal and it supports command-line. So, the question seem to be solved.

Comment: @Aaron it would be more appropriate if you allowed Nirmal to answer since it's his idea ;)